# Returning rows that are not in a left join table

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have the following tables for a voting system:

1. nominee_categories - Categories for nominees
2. nominees - Contains the nominees where a nominee is linked to the nominee_categories
3. votes - Contains the relationship by user and votes with a user_id and nominee_id column

I am looking to return all of the rows (nominees) where I have not voted for a specific category yet. The votes table does not reference the category, but the nominee which in return has a category field.

If I for example have category1 with 2 nominees, and category2 with 5 nominees, if I (userID) have voted for category 1, my result set should return only nominees for category2 with the 5 nominees

I have the following SQL that seems to work, but I cannot imagine this being the way to do it as it seems ugly and im clearing missing something. Any ideas on how to clean this up would be fantastic :)

```
 $nominees = $this->model->get("
            SELECT
                `nc`.`name` AS `category`,`nc`.`id` AS `categoryId`,
                `n`.`name`,`surname`,`dealership`,`description`,`n`.`id` 
            FROM 
                `nominee_categories` `nc`
                LEFT JOIN `nominees` `n` on `nc`.`id`=`n`.`nominee_category_id` 
                LEFT JOIN `votes` `v` ON `v`.`nominee_id`=`n`.`id` 
                LEFT JOIN `users` `u` ON `u`.`id`=`v`.`user_id` 
            WHERE 
                `nc`.`id` NOT IN (
                    SELECT 
                        `nc`.`id` 
                    FROM 
                        `votes` `v` 
                        LEFT JOIN `nominees` `n` ON `n`.`id`=`v`.`nominee_id` 
                        LEFT JOIN `nominee_categories` `nc` ON `nc`.`id`=`n`.`nominee_category_id`
                    WHERE 
                        `nc`.`id`=`nc`.`id` 
                        AND `user_id`=?
                    )
        ", [
        $this->userID
    ]);
```

Comment: Please provide the tables structure, sample data and desired result [mre]

Comment: Use WHERE NOT EXISTS - this is more clear for your task.